# C# Creating list of Objects like the Slides panel in PowerPoint

Tags: c#

I can not figure out how to graphically representate objects. I want some kind of rectangles, maybe even buttons that ill dynamicaly generate, the user will be able to click them for action and change their order. I will use WPF or Windows Forms Apps.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that searching for an external resource (like a control library) may be considered offtopic here. Additionally, you didn't even specifiy which UI framework to use. `WPF`, `UWP`, `Winforms` or even `Xamarin`? If you don't add some details, your question will be closed becaus it's to broad or offtopic..

Comment: @ventiseis Thank you. Iam not looking for a library, iam looking for an example how to create visual representation of objects.